# Secure Laravel URL using it for a cron job

Tags: php, laravel, cron

How can I secure a `GET` URL in Laravel so it can only called by my server via cron job` only.

I am using GoDaddy Shared hosting.

Thanks

Comment: You use [Laravels scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling)

Comment: how can do it without using Laravels scheduling

Comment: What have you come up with? Have you done any "research"? Stack Overflow is a [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
& [Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) website for specific programming questions. Maybe use a top secret GET parameter that only you know, Without that parameter nothing will be executed. Could be "easy" to "hack" though. Why not go with Laravel scheduling? Any specific reason?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use Laravel's scheduling? It works off a cron job anyway, so if you can set a cron job up, you can use it. And if you write it as an Artisan task, it can't be called via HTTP, making it more secure.